# SQL if recordset does not match error condition, Access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

This code is working for modifying a textbox if there is variable *IntVer* has a  value in it. *IntVer* is the variable holding the textbox version. But if the user initiates the add command from an empty text box they get a type mismatch error. Which in fact is a SQL error because it can't match the string because the *IntVer* does not exist so it result in an error because it can't find the record.

How can I prevent this from happening? I thought adding the `recordcount <>0` would do it but the SQL command executes before the recordcount.

So the error makes sense to me, I just don't know how to fix it.

Thank you for your help,

Maxine

```vb
Private Sub cmdMod_Click()
  Dim strSelSQL As String

  strSelSQL = "SELECT EmpSWDetails.AssetID, EmpSWDetails.[" & SOFT & "] FROM EmpSWDetails " _
                & "WHERE (((EmpSWDetails.AssetID)='" & Asset & "') AND ((EmpSWDetails.[" & SOFT & "])='" & IntVer & "'));"

  Dim con As ADODB.Connection
  Set con = Application.CurrentProject.Connection

  Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
  Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

  rs.Open strSelSQL, con, adOpenDynamic, adLockPessimistic

  If rs.RecordCount <> 0 Then
      rs.Fields(SOFT) = SELVER   'update version to new version
  Else
      rs!AssetID = Asset
      rs.Fields(SOFT) = SELVER
  End If

  rs.Update
  rs.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Try `NZ` with a value that will not return any records: `& Nz(IntVer, "bogus") &`.

Comment: Or use `If Not IsNull(IntVer) Then` so code doesn't even try to open recordset if there is no value to work with. You can even chastise the user with a message that they failed to provide data.

Answer (score 1):

Nz() is probably your best option if you want it to catch only this specific Error (using Nz will handle both "object=Null and object="" at the same time making the if statement shorter, more efficient, and more readable).

```
Private Sub cmdMod_Click()
  Dim strSelSQL As String

  If Nz(intVer,"")="" then 
     msgbox "Please enter data.", vbOkOnly, "Required"
  Else       
      strSelSQL = "SELECT EmpSWDetails.AssetID, EmpSWDetails.[" & SOFT & "] FROM EmpSWDetails " _
                & "WHERE (((EmpSWDetails.AssetID)='" & Asset & "') AND ((EmpSWDetails.[" & SOFT & "])='" & IntVer & "'));"

      <the rest of your code>
  End If
End Sub
```

If you want it to catch all errors you can implement an error handler. Something like the following

```
  Private Sub cmdMod_Click()
  Dim strSelSQL As String
  On Error GoTo Error_Handler

  <code>

  Exit_Error_Handler:
       Exit Sub

  Error_Handler:
       Msgbox "Error: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & "Description: " & Err.Description
       'You can also put code to handle specific errors 
       'For Example: If Err.Number = 13 Then Msgbox "Data required in Textbox", vbOkOnly, "Required" End If
           GoTo Exit_Error_Handler
  End Sub
```

Error handling in Access is the the only thing I can think of where I would ever endorse the use of a GoTo statement.

Comment: Thank you so much this is great!

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. The button simple did nothing, even though I kept it real simple like your example and set it to display a msgbox. @billyhoes